# Javascript random background image change onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

I have 6 ahref boxes on a page which all have different sized background images, what I would like to do is onload get 3 random boxes bg image file extensions, and swap them over for gifs. So every time the page refreshes 3 images are different. Im not entirely sure how to do this, as i want the positions to be random, but have the control by changing the urls and not changing for completely random image.

Comment: Your question is a little difficult to read. If I understand: you have three boxes all with different background images. You want to pick a random image for each box every time the page loads?

Comment: Sorry I have 6 boxes in total, on load I would like to change the background images on 3 of them for example. But it has to be a random 3 boxes on each page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a random 3 nodes from your list you can select them, convert them to an array then pick one by index between 0 and nodeList.length:

```
(function (document) {
    var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box'),
        background = '',
        index = 0;

    // Convert the nodeList to an Array
    boxes = Array.prototype.slice.call(boxes);

    // Returns a random integer between min and max
    // Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }

    for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        // Pick a random node
        index = getRandomInt(1, boxes.length) - 1;
        // Background
        background = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(boxes[index])
            .backgroundImage
            .replace('.jpg', '.gif');
        boxes[index].style.cssText = "background-image:" + background;
        // Remove that node so we don't get it again
        boxes.splice(index, 1);
    }

}(document));
```

[Here's a Fiddle to show it in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/linssen/Y4Yya/)

Comment: Thanks Wil, the randomness is correct. How easy is it to get the current background of the box, and change the extension. Can I do it with something like url("../static/images/" + boxes[index] +".gif")

Comment: I've just updated my answer to show how to swap the file extension from `.jpg` to `.gif`. Then you can have one bg image called `mybg.jpg` that will be swapped for one in the same location called `mybg.gif`.

Comment: thanks Wil :) nearly there, the extension isnt showing so im getting file /mybg without the .gif

Comment: I noticed that I'd left the `url(...)` part of the style in, we didn't need that and i've updated the example (try that). What are all of the image extensions you're using.

Comment: i get empty style tags now, im only using jpgs and gifs

Comment: You'll probably want the computed style then if it's trying to get external CSS. I've updated the fiddle and example again.

Comment: Thanks for your help Wil, its now working how I wanted :) thanks again

Answer (score -1):

```
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)
```

This will generate a random number between 0-5. So you can go ahead and select the respective child

```
$( "ul li:nth-child(randomNum )" ).css('background-image', 'url(http://url you want.com)')
```

If you want random images also try either naming the images so that you can use another random variable to get the images by appending them to the `url()`

Comment: This would randomise one background image, where I think OP actually only wants to change 3 (randomly selected.) It's also assuming he's using jQuery.

Comment: for using different background images it will be better if he stores the image as img1.jpg , img2.jpg .... upto he wants and use another random variable and do a `$('#img').attr('src', '../img'+randomVariable+'.jpg')`